# .Net developer new to Objective-C. Need some critique and suggestions

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I've created one of my first apps using Objective-C. Being a noob, there's a lot of stuff I want to do, but don't know how to apply it in Objective-C. Please take a look at the method below (which I created from scratch) and tell me what you would do to make it better. Obviously I've duplicated code across 2 UILabels, but I'd like to simplify that (I hate duplicating code) but I'm unaware what the best way to do it is. I just need suggestions which will help me better understand the right way to do stuff in Objective-C

timeText and dateText are of type UILabel

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (isRearranging)
    {
        NSLog(@"touchesMoved");
        NSLog(@"touches=%@,event=%@",touches,event);
        //TOUCH INFO
        UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
        //FRAME INFO
        float timeHalfWidth = timeText.frame.size.width / 2;
        float timeHalfHeight = timeText.frame.size.height / 2;
        CGRect timeTextRect = CGRectMake(timeText.center.x - (timeHalfWidth), timeText.cener.y - (timeHalfHeight), timeText.frame.size.width, timeText.frame.size.height);
        float dateHalfWidth = dateText.frame.size.width / 2;
        float dateHalfHeight = dateText.frame.size.height / 2;
        CGRect dateTextRect = CGRectMake(dateText.center.x - (dateHalfWidth), dateText.center.y - (dateHalfHeight), dateText.frame.size.width, dateText.frame.size.height);
        //IF TIME TEXT
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(timeTextRect,previousLocation))
        {
            CGPoint item = timeText.center;
            CGPoint diff;
            diff.x = previousLocation.x - item.x;
            diff.y = previousLocation.y - item.y;
            CGPoint newLoc;
            newLoc.x = currentLocation.x - diff.x;
            newLoc.y = currentLocation.y - diff.y;
            if (newLoc.x<timeHalfWidth)
                newLoc.x = timeHalfWidth;
            if (newLoc.y<timeHalfHeight)
                newLoc.y = timeHalfHeight;
            [timeText setCenter:(newLoc)];
        }
        //IF DATE TEXT
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(dateTextRect,previousLocation))
        {
            CGPoint item = dateText.center;
            CGPoint diff;
            diff.x = previousLocation.x - item.x;
            diff.y = previousLocation.y - item.y;
            CGPoint newLoc;
            newLoc.x = currentLocation.x - diff.x;
            newLoc.y = currentLocation.y - diff.y;
            if (newLoc.x<dateHalfWidth)
                newLoc.x = dateHalfWidth;
            if (newLoc.y<dateHalfHeight)
                newLoc.y = dateHalfHeight;
            [dateText setCenter:(newLoc)];      
        }
    }
    touchMoved = YES;
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: edit your post, highlight all your code, and click the code button in the text editor.

Comment: Step one, format your code when posting.

Answer (score 4):

A first step, independent from the language you are working in, would be to follow [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - most of your code is the same for both labels.
Then there is already functionality for hit-testing in the SDK, e.g. [`-hitTest:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#jumpTo_63) or [`-pointInside:withEvent:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW2):

```
NSArray *labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:timeText, dateText, nil];
for (UILabel *label in labels) {
    if ([label pointInside:previousLocation withEvent:nil]) {
        [self relocateLabel:label]; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: DRY is why I specifically mentioned that I duplicated code. I wanted to see someone rewrite my duplication in the correct way. You gave me exactly what I was looking for.

What if I wanted to use mixed types in that array? i.e. a couple UILabel and a couple UIImageView. Is there a way to compare types or use generics?

This is a poor guess/example

    for (NSObject *obj in objects)
    {
        if (label.type==UILabel)
            [self relocateLabel:obj];
        else if (label.type==UIImageView)
            [self relocateImage:obj];
    }

Comment: @Ricky: Objective-C message passing is dynamic and both examples derive from `UIView` - so as long as you only use methods from `UIView` make that `for(UIView *view in views)` and `-relocateView:(UIView*)view`.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer an additional question posed by asker in a comment. Quote:

> What if I wanted to use mixed types in that array? i.e. a couple UILabel and a couple UIImageView. Is there a way to compare types or use generics? This is a poor guess/example for (NSObject *obj in objects) { if (label.type==UILabel) [self relocateLabel:obj]; else if (label.type==UIImageView) [self relocateImage:obj]; }

As Georg Fritzsche answered there, Objective-C messaging is dynamic. Object will be "queried" if it supports that message at runtime, and if so, it will execute the method associated with the message. Method/message name is called a "selector".

If you explicitly want to figure out object's class, you can do that as well.

```
if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
{
    // your code here
}
```

If you just want to figure out if the target object responds to a selector (that is, implements a method):

```
if([view respondsToSelector:@selector(relocateView:)])
{
    // your code here
}
```

Selectors are derived from method names by omitting arguments themselves, leaving colons intact and appending everything closely. For example, if you had a message send (that is, method call): `[thing moveTowardsObject:door movementType:XYZ_CRAWL]`, its selector would be: `moveTowardsObject:movementType:` and you'd get it using `@selector(moveTowardsObject:movementType:)`.

In a loop such as what Georg posted, you typically want to just check if the target object responds to a selector, since otherwise an exception would be thrown, and Objective-C code rarely catches exceptions as part of a normal code flow (as opposed to what Python developers do).